# i want to integrate sms api to my laravel5-4 project but am having error pointing to my controller "array conversion to string"

Tags: php, laravel-5, infobip, infobip-api

**my controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function manyMessage(Request $request){

    $message = $request->input("message");
    $mobile = $request->input("mobile");
    $encodeMessage = urlencode($message);
    $authKey = 'BHu2TCgKYAymjrc5iX6ge1NyjePaK1vrrz2e0LbKhTbm3qCIuALM73Fonq0F4EaKvc5zKT7T2PglcjH8DDuB2rhiPL7WXPVr7aDu';
    $senderId = 'followupvisitatrion';
    $route = 4;
    $postData = $request->all();
    $mobileNumber = implode('',$postData['mobile']);
    $arr = str_split($mobileNumber,11);
    $mobiles = implode(",",$arr);
    $data = array(
        'authKey' => $authKey,
        'mobiles' => $mobiles,
        'message' => $encodeMessage,
        'sender' => $senderId,
        'route' => $route,

    );
    $url = "https://api.infobip.com";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $url,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    ));

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

   $output = curl_exec($ch);

   if(curl_errno($ch)){

       echo 'error :'. curl_error($ch);

   }

   curl_close($ch);
    Session::flash('success', 'Message sent Successfully!');
   return redirect("/records");
}
}
```

**my view**

```html
<form role="form" action="{{url("/sendMessage")}}" method="post">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <textarea type="hidden" class="form-control" row="4">Write Text</textarea><br>
                                <input type="submit" class="pull-left btn btn-primary btn-small" value="Send"/><br /><br />

                                <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="select_all"/> Select All<br/><br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                New Converts / First Timer
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                                        <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                            <th>Home Address</th>
                                                            <th>Email Address</th>
                                                            <th>Date</th>
                                                            <th>Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        @if(isset($record))
                                                            @foreach($record as $record)

                                                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="{{$record->phone}}"></td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->first_name}} - {{$record->last_name}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->phone}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->home_address}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{$record->email}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($record->created_at)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
                                                                    <td><div class="">
                                                                            <a href="{{URL::to('/editNewConvert')}}/{{$record->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
                                                                            <a href="{{URL::to('/deleteNewConvert')}}/{{$record->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
                                                                        </div></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        @endif
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
</form>
```

**ERROR**

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Array to string conversion
in MessageController.php (line 37)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Array to string conversion', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blog\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\MessageController.php', 37, array('request' => object(Request), 'message' => null, 'mobile' => array('08028479963'), 'encodeMessage' => '', 'authKey' => 'BHu2TCgKYAymjrc5iX6ge1NyjePaK1vrrz2e0LbKhTbm3qCIuALM73Fonq0F4EaKvc5zKT7T2PglcjH8DDuB2rhiPL7WXPVr7aDu', 'senderId' => 'followupvisitatrion', 'route' => 4, 'postData' => array('_token' => 'p7Cg8f0nQzCjwuuVz83WmQngvp7zeiGnQRQS8FPi', 'dataTables-example_length' => '10', 'mobile' => 'Array'), 'mobileNumber' => '08028479963', 'arr' => array('08028479963'), 'mobiles' => '08028479963', 'data' => array('authKey' => 'BHu2TCgKYAymjrc5iX6ge1NyjePaK1vrrz2e0LbKhTbm3qCIuALM73Fonq0F4EaKvc5zKT7T2PglcjH8DDuB2rhiPL7WXPVr7aDu', 'mobiles' => '08028479963', 'message' => '', 'sender' => 'followupvisitatrion', 'route' => 4), 'url' => 'https://api.infobip.com', 'ch' => resource))
at curl_setopt_array(resource, array('https://api.infobip.com', 1, 1, array('_token' => 'p7Cg8f0nQzCjwuuVz83WmQngvp7zeiGnQRQS8FPi', 'dataTables-example_length' => '10', 'mobile' => 'Array')))
in MessageController.php (line 37)
```

Comment: which line is 37?

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,` need to be `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,` .check and let me know

Comment: thanks it works, no more showing error